# Get first character from string in handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js, jinja2

I am new to handlebars and trying to get the first letter from a looped string i.e

```
{{#each message}}
 <div class='name'>{{this.user}}</div>
 <div class='img'><h1 class="abbr">{{this.user.charAt(0)}}</h1></div>
 <div class='text'>
 <div>
 {{this.text}}
   </div>
   </div>
  {{/each}}
```

I have tried {{this.text[0]}} and {{this.text.charAt(0)}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Preparation-Script to achieve this : [HandleBars Documents](https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/helper-this-context.html)

must register helper and use it:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('returnOnlyZeroindex', function () {
   return this.user[0]
})
```

and use like this:

```
<p>{{returnOnlyZeroindex}}</p>
```

Comment: I actually saw this in the docs earlier but didn't pay much attention to it but having a second look now it is exactly what I was looking for and it worked.